# How to change date for specific id

Tags: javascript

I would like to create a script that will change the day/month/year according to real date.

I have 3 id's.

```
<span id="date1">September 14, 2016</span>

<span id="date2">September 13, 2016</span>

<span id="date3">September 12, 2016</span>
```

I want to change the dates every day like this date1 = real date, date2 = yesterday, date3 = before yesterday.

Here is some javascript i came up but it doesn't work as i need.

```
function datums(datuminsh) {
                var months = new Array(12);
                months[0] = "January";
                months[1] = "February";
                months[2] = "March";
                months[3] = "April";
                months[4] = "May";
                months[5] = "June";
                months[6] = "July";
                months[7] = "August";
                months[8] = "September";
                months[9] = "October";
                months[10] = "November";
                months[11] = "December";

                var current_date = new Date();
                current_date.setDate(current_date.getDate() - datuminsh);
                month_value = current_date.getMonth();
                day_value = current_date.getDate();
                year_value = current_date.getFullYear();

                document.write(months[month_value] + " " + day_value + ", " + year_value);
                }   

document.getElementById("date1").innerHTML = datums(0);
document.getElementById("date2").innerHTML = datums(1);
document.getElementById("date3").innerHTML = datums(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. Yesterday's date is simply today's date less one. The day before yesterday is today's date minus two.

```js
var yesterday = new Date();
yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 1);
```

```js
var beforeYesterday = new Date();
beforeYesterday.setDate(beforeYesterday.getDate() - 2);
```

The only thing you have to do is run this code everyday to disply actual data. There is a node package for this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule

Use this snippet:

```
var j = schedule.scheduleJob({hour: 00, minute: 00}, function(){
    walk.on('dir', function (dir, stat) {
        uploadDir.push(dir);
    });
});
```